# How to use params inside navigationOptions with React Navigation 5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

Sorry for this question i don't understand the other question's answers because they are not really the same as what i want. I am a beginner with this.

**This is my App.js: (new way of App.js)**

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator()

export default function App() {
  return <NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator>
<Stack.Screen options={{title: 'Profile'},Profile.navigationOptions} name="Profile" component={Profile}/>
name="AccountOverview" component={AccountOverview}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
}
```

**This is my profile.js navigationOptions**

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
    const { params = {} } = navigation.state;

    if (params.facebookName) {
      var usernameTitle = params.facebookName || "";
    } else {
      var usernameTitle = params.usernameValue || "";
    }
    return {
      title: "Welcome " + usernameTitle,

      headerRight: () =>
        <TouchableOpacity style={styles.btn} onPress={params.removeItemValue}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>Log out</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>

    };
  };
```

The error i am getting is `undefined is not an object (evaluating 'navigation.state.params')`

I can't understand the documentation either from React Navigation's website.

So i hope i will get a anwer targeting my exact way of code.

I would really appreciate it and give you and accepted answer for your solution.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use params in three ways:

1. when defining a screen inside stack navigator you can send initial params to it :
       `<Stack.Screen ... initialParams={{ facebookName: "developer" }}` />
2. when navigating to a screen from other screens in the stack :
       `navigation.navigate("Profile", { facebookName: "developer" })`
3. you can also update a screen's param from inside of it :
       `navigation.setParams({ title: "new title" })`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was watching a tutorial earlier and he used the second one. I still don't know how to use 1 and 3 but i will figure it out eventually. Thank you for your time